# Installing LPSolve for Matlab on Windows

Tags: windows, matlab, installation, lpsolve

I'm really stuck and need some help.
I'm trying to install lpsolve for use with Matlab. I've tried following the instructions on the lpsolve webpage but don't find them very helpful. I've downloaded:

```
  lp_solve_5.5.2.0_MATLAB_exe_win64

  lp_solve_5.5.3.0_dev_win64
```

I'm running 64bit Windows 7 and using Matlab 2014b. I've unzipped both downloads. The contents of lp_solve_5.5.3.0_dev_win64 is in a folder which has been added to Matlabs path.

lp_solve_5.5.2.0_MATLAB_exe_win64 has been extracted to a folder in the System 32 folder. This folder has also been added to Matlabs path also.

When I type mxlpsolve in Matlab, I get:

```
 mxlpsolve driver not found !!!
 Check if mxlpsolve.dll is on your system and in a directory known to MATLAB.
 Press enter to see the paths where MATLAB looks for the driver.
```

The file lpsolve55.dll was in lp_solve_5.5.2.0_MATLAB_exe_win64 but not mxlpsolve.dll. I'm really confused.

Any help you could give me would be really appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: Copy mxlpsolve.dll into C:\Windows\System32

Comment: @Carlochess, I have the same problem described in above question. I have the "mxlpsolve.dll" file but whereever I put it, MATLAB does not recognize and gives the error. I put it in a path that MATLAB searches, and also tried to put it in System32 folder. Ive also tried to change .dll to .mexw32 in filename but still fails. Why MATLAB does not see that file exists?